# Saving model object in django throws no error but attribute value doesn't change

Tags: django, models, save

I get a model object, change an attribute, save it and it still has the old attribute:

```
>>> g = SiteProfile.objects.get(pk=3)
>>> g.renew_date
datetime.date(2010, 4, 11)
>>> g.renew_date = date.today()+timedelta(days=365)
>>> g.renew_date
datetime.date(2011, 4, 11)
>>> g.save()
>>> g.renew_date
datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 11, 16, 57, 4, 192684)
```

Anyone know if this is an issue with the database or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

The issue was that the field `renew_date` had the argument `auto_now` set to `True` as such:

```
renew_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
```

I understood `auto_now` to mean that the current date will be used when creating the object, but it turns out that's not the case:

> DateField.auto_now
>
> Automatically set
>   the field to now every time the object
>   is saved. Useful for "last-modified"
>   timestamps. Note that the current date
>   is always used; it's not just a
>   default value that you can override.
>
> From [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now).

What I needed was `auto_now_add` which:

> Automatically set the field to now
>   when the object is first created.
>   Useful for creation of timestamps.
>   Note that the current date is always
>   used; it's not just a default value
>   that you can override.

So, after changing my `renew_date` field:

```
renew_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
```

it all works, just fine :)

```
>>> g = SelectStatProfile.objects.get(pk=3)
>>> g.renew_date
datetime.date(2010, 4, 11)
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> g.renew_date = date.today()+timedelta(days=365)
>>> g.renew_date
datetime.date(2011, 4, 11)
>>> g.save()
>>> g.renew_date
datetime.date(2011, 4, 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the django document for the automatic commit. I guess you have to enable the automatic commit to accept the change immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have set `DISABLE_TRANSACTION_MANAGEMENT` to `False`:

As the [Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#how-to-globally-deactivate-transaction-management) says:

> If you do this, Django won't provide any automatic transaction management whatsoever. Middleware will no longer implicitly commit transactions, and you'll need to roll management yourself. This even requires you to commit changes done by middleware somewhere else.